# Weighted mean in pandas - string indices must be integers

Tags: python, pandas

I am going to calculate weighted average based on csv file. I have already loaded columns: A, B which contains float values.
My csv file:

```
A   B
170.804 2854
140.924 510
164.842 3355
```

Pattern

```
(w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ...) / (w1 + w2 + w3 + ...)
```

My code:

```
c = df['B']                                     # ok
wa = (df['B'] * df['A']).sum() / df['B'].sum()  # TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: What's your expected output for your sample input?

Comment: This error does not correspond to your code. This error appears when you try to index a string with a string. So your df has to be a string. Check what df is

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you might try this (the line of code you wrote should work as well):

```
wa = df['A'].dot(df['B']) / df['B'].sum()

print(wa)

165.55897693109094
```